# How to check if parameter is empty in SQL function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-function, table-valued-parameters

I have in my function this TVP parameter:

```
@SiteTypeId [dbo].[intArray]
```

How can I check if this parameter is empty?

Comment: Perhaps you can try using NullIf function?

Answer (score 1):

*How can I check if this parameter is empty?* Here considering empty as zero records in table since it is a table valued parameter

You can check it using `IF NOT EXISTS`

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from @SiteTypeId)
Begin
--statements
End
```